# contentful rich text - blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I am trying to render the rich text from this query but the page is blank. Im really confused because the docs only show the example of how an image asset is rendered. Can anyone help??

I am trying to show the rich text in the format it was written in contentful i.e the first line should be bold

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"

export const query = graphql`
query MyQuery($slug: String) {
    contentfulLongPost(Slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      title
      updatedAt(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
      body {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
  
`;


const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: (text) => <span>{text}</span>
    
  },
  
}



const CaseStudy = ({data}) => {
    const { bodyRichText } = data.contentfulLongPost


     

    return (
        <Layout>
        <div>   {bodyRichText && renderRichText(bodyRichText, options)}</div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default CaseStudy;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't you mean to be passing `data.contentfulLongPost.body.raw`? Also, you should not be dropping script tags into your page to load React if you're using Gatsby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any `bodyRichText` field so I don't understand why you are destructuring at:

```
const { bodyRichText } = data.contentfulLongPost
```

This is extracted from the docs, where their data structure has a `bodyRichText`. You are accessing directly to `raw` so you can omit it. Assuming that your query works (and it's a lot to assume, test it at `localhost:8000/___graphql`), I think you are looking for:

```
const CaseStudy = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
        <div>   {data.contentfulLongPost.body && renderRichText(data.contentfulLongPost.body, options)}</div>
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

But I guess you'll need to tweak more the query. I'm not sure at all that you are fetching properly the `raw` field in all use-cases.

Comment: i get this error:

Comment: Error in function Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev

Comment: if i console.log(data), i get raw

Comment: You'll need to put more of your side... do you have `data.contentfulLongPost`? Can you paste he output???

Comment: Don't overload the comment sections, please: You've edited the first snippet (again) so the data structure has changed (again). Use this `renderRichText(data.contentfulLongPost.body, options)`